# How to inject FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider to SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, mvcsitemapprovider

I don't know how to set default visibility provider with Unity. I used internal DI container and it works but with external all nodes are displayed.

In `web.config`

```
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="true"/>
```

In `MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension`

```
// Visibility Providers
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>("defaultProvider");
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider>("trimVisibilityProvider");

this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy, SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>(this.Container.ResolveAll<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>().ToArray()),
    new InjectionParameter<string>("defaultProvider")
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider), the default provider is resolved using the [.NET type FullName string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy, SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>(this.Container.ResolveAll<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>().ToArray()),
    new InjectionParameter<string>("MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider")
));
```

**Auto-Registration**

Do note that all implementations of `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` are automatically registered by convention in your MVC assembly, so there is no need to add these lines:

```
// Visibility Providers
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>("defaultProvider");
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider>("trimVisibilityProvider");
```

Here is the auto-registration code for Unity. If you have `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` implementations in another assembly, you can add that assembly name here.

```
var allAssemblies = new Assembly[] { currentAssembly, siteMapProviderAssembly };
var excludeTypes = new Type[] { 
    // Use this array to add types you wish to explicitly exclude from convention-based  
    // auto-registration. By default all types that either match I[TypeName] = [TypeName] or 
    // I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter will be automatically wired up as long as they don't 
    // have the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
    //
    // If you want to override a type that follows the convention, you should add the name 
    // of either the implementation name or the interface that it inherits to this list and 
    // add your manual registration code below. This will prevent duplicate registrations 
    // of the types from occurring. 

    // Example:
    // typeof(SiteMap),
    // typeof(SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy)
};
var multipleImplementationTypes = new Type[]  { 
    typeof(ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver), 
    typeof(ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider), // <- These are automatically registered by convention
    typeof(IDynamicNodeProvider) 
};

// ...

// Multiple implementations of strategy based extension points (and not decorated with [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute]).
CommonConventions.RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
    (interfaceType, implementationType) => this.Container.RegisterType(interfaceType, implementationType, implementationType.Name, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()),
    multipleImplementationTypes,
    allAssemblies,
    excludeTypes,
    string.Empty);
```